# Why Net force is not zero and hence COM is not fixed

Tags: kinematics, momentum

In a classical center of mass problem where a man is standing on a boat and then walks to another end we solve it by the fact that the COM is fixed or at rest as the net force is zero- forces are only normal and weight.

In another problem where a block is on the top of a wedge and sliding and surface is frictionless why the Net Force is not zero (in both x andy ) like the former one. Here ,also, if we consider block and wedge as a system, the only external forces are weight and normal of the block-wedge system.

Comment: Why do you say that the COM is not fixed in the case of the wedge?

Comment: According to book, in second case net force is zero only in x direction i.e  Fx=0 and Fy is not zero hence center of mass is fixed along x axis.

Comment: Is the man walking along the wedge?

Comment: In second case , we have only block and wedge. Block is sliding on wedge and hence wedge will move backward as the surface is frictionless

Comment: The COM accelerates in the $y$ direction, right?  Keep in mind that this is not a rigid system.

Comment: Yes, but it means net force is not zero in y direction and that's my confusion as in both the problems if we consider man+boat or block-wedge as a system only force is weight and normal which cancels itself

Comment: Can you justify the statement that weight and normal force cancel?

Comment: I was assuming both block and wedge as one object(system) hence the only force i.e present is weight of the combined object similar to the case of man+boat system where according to book Net force is zero. Also,Is the man-boat system rigid?

Answer (score 0):

If the block slides along the wedge (which is frictionless with respect to the horizontal direction) then its center of mass is lowering. While it is accelerating down, gravity (an external force) is doing work on it.

Also - while it is accelerating, there will be a lower normal force from the wedge on the block. This comes directly from a balance of forces - the vertical acceleration comes from the difference between the vertical component of the normal force, and gravity. The wedge does not accelerate vertically - and so the vertical force of the ground onto the wedge will equal the vertical force between block and wedge. This force is less than the force of gravity on the block plus wedge - so there is a net vertical force.

By contrast, there is no external horizontal force.

In summary: There is an external force (gravity) at work on the system. This force needs to be carefully accounted for.

Comment: When we consider wedge and block as one system do we need to consider normal force between them? Why we don't have center of mass changing in x direction.

Comment: @Raj see my edit.